# 2 join conditions codeigniter giving error

Tags: codeigniter, join, conditional-statements

I have 2 tables - for orders and for documents for these orders. I want to show all orders from first table and if there are documents for these orders, to show date of documents(I take date from table `documents`). 
I'm trying to make 2 join conditions because in table `documents` if I only join on idOrder, there are more than 1 row and I have to join on documents.name to be same as $this->uri->segment(3).
But I'm using the following code and it gives me error. Could I use 2 join conditions in this way:

My model is:

```php
<?php
 public function get_all_orders($user_id){

        $this->db->select('ordersheader.*, customer.name as customerName,documents.date_make');
        $this->db->from('ordersheader');
        $this->db->join('customer', 'ordersheader.idCustomer = customer.idCustomer');
        $this->db->join('documents', 'ordersheader.idOrder = documents.idOrder','left'); 
        $this->db->join('documents as D', 'D.name="declaration"','left'); 


        $this->db->where('ordersheader.user_id', $user_id);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

Edited: I found solution. But it's written in pure sql, how to write it with Codeingiter syntax? My new working code is:

```html
<?php
 $query=("SELECT ordersheader.*, customer.name as customerName,documents.date_make,documents.deactivated_at
            FROM ordersheader JOIN customer ON  ordersheader.idCustomer = customer.idCustomer
            LEFT JOIN documents
            ON ordersheader.idOrder = documents.idOrder AND documents.name = '".$document."' 
            WHERE ordersheader.user_id = '".$user_id."' ");
 $result = $this->db->query($query);
      return $result->result_array();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is wrong in your query

```
 $this->db->join('documents as D', 'D.name="declaration"','left');
```

you can compare column using `where` clause

```
public function get_all_orders($user_id){

        $this->db->select('ordersheader.*, customer.name as customerName,documents.date_make');
        $this->db->from('ordersheader');
        $this->db->join('customer', 'ordersheader.idCustomer = customer.idCustomer');
        $this->db->join('documents', 'ordersheader.idOrder = documents.idOrder','left'); 
       // $this->db->join('documents as D', 'D.name="declaration"','left'); / comment this line

        $this->db->where('documents.name', 'declaration');
        $this->db->where('ordersheader.user_id', $user_id);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

Comment: I edited my question. I found solution, but how to write it with Codeigniter syntax? :)